# Is there any way to revert to an earlier playthrough?

Tags: rogue-legacy

I've gotten to playthrough 3, and experienced an enormous jump in difficulty. Is there any way for me to revert back to playthrough 2 so I can upgrade my manor further before progressing?

Comment: Wups, you're right. Guess my search didn't use the right words.